# Why does sftp hide the log from stdout?

Tags: cron, io-redirection, sftp

I have a script `a.sh`, which has an `sftp` command:

```
echo "Starting to sftp..."
sftp xxx@xxx.xxx.xxx.xx << END_SCRIPT
ls
mput *.csv.gz
bye

END_SCRIPT
echo "Sftp successfully."
```

If I run it interactively, the log output from `sftp` is shown. However, if I set it in a crontab and redirect the stdout to a file using `>`, there will be only the output from the two `echo` statements. How can I get the log from the `sftp` command?

EDIT:

I tried the following forms and it didn't work too.

sftp -b batch_file.txt xxx@xxx.xxx.xx.xx ( redirect from cron )

sftp -b batch_file.txt xxx@xxx.xxx.xx.xx >> some_file.log ( redirect from cron + redirect from this line )

I think the problem should be related to the nature of sftp that it is supposed to be run interactively, as stated in the man page. But I cannot find the solution.

**My distribution** : `Red Hat Enterprise Linux AS release 3 (Taroon Update 2)`

**the crontab entry**:

```
52 14 * * * sh /home/xxx/testing/xxx.sh > /home/xxx/testing/xxx_`date +\%Y\%m\%d`.log
```

And the log is created with a time matching the crontab entry.

**ssh version**:

```
OpenSSH_3.6.1p2, SSH protocols 1.5/2.0, OpenSSL 0x0090701f
```

EDIT:

I found that if I redirect the output of sftp in the script file to an text file, the message from sftp is logged. Then I remove the log file and scheduled it with cron. After the cron execution, the log file is generated but have no message from sftp. Instead, it only contain log from other statement inside the script file.

If I redirect the output of sftp in script file and run it interactively, the log are perfectly fine. However if I scheduled it with cron ( no redirect in the crontab entry, just simply schedule it ), the log from sftp is gone too.

Comment: Why not use tar/cpio over ssh to transfer?

Comment: This got flagged for migration to SO, but it's far more on-topic here; this is a question about `sftp` or `cron`, depending on where the problem is

Comment: I just ran a quick check, and `sftp foo@bar.com << EOF > sftpout.txt` gave me most of `sftp`'s output where it was supposed to go. What version of `ssh` and what distribution are you using?

Comment: On a related note, *how* precisely are you redirecting it in cron? Can you show us the exact `crontab` entry?

Comment: Red Hat Enterprise Linux AS release 3 (Taroon Update 2). How can I check the ssh version?

Comment: @gunbuster363 `ssh -V`

Comment: Did you try -v (verbose) option? Output could be reduced because not running under a terminal, this is common practice.

Comment: @Netch Tried. The verbose message are also coming from sftp, it is also gone.

Comment: What about redirecting the standard error stream? Some tools output informative/debugging messages to `stderr`, as these are not the *main* output of the tool.

Comment: No. I tried 2>&1, didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

From the looks of it, output redirection *is* occurring, but you probably want to include `stderr`, too. Try this in your crontab:

```
52 14 * * * sh /home/xxx/testing/xxx.sh > /home/xxx/testing/xxx_`date +\%Y\%m\%d`.log 2>&1
```

Note the `2>&1` at the end. It means: "redirect file descriptor 2, `stderr`, to whatever file descriptor 1, `stdout`, is." Because you already redirected `stdout` to the file, `stderr` will end up in there as well.

Comment: No it doesn't work and not making sense too. Since I can redirect the std output of sftp when I run the script manually, it is clear that the output isn't in std err channel. And I tried it too, it didn't work.

Comment: I found out the reason. I must admit you are right, though the 2>&1 didn't give me much clue when I first tried it. I will post the solution as an asnwer.